# Simple "Hello World" Java program not working in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I opened Eclipse, named the project "firstProject" and then made a class called `Apples`. This is the code:

```
public class Apples {
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       System.out.println("Hello World!");
   }
}
```

I've got this error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at firstProjject.Apples.main(Apples.java:2)

What is the problem?

Comment: Please show us your `package ...` line

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder Has to be because the stacktrace shows the Apples file

Answer (score 0):

You should create your `Apples.java` in src folder of  `firstProject` project.
I have written file as

```
package firstProject;

public class Apples {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

}
```

It is printing required String.

Comment: I have also used the eclipse IDE

Comment: So the problem is that I have no idea what  a "package declaration" is or even what the keyword "package" means. I guess I'll learn all this in time. Thank you, this helped. I just wish this type of clear answer was given when I was searching stackOverflow for my problem. But it is quite silly how questions from a beginner earn negative reps. Thanks again though.

Comment: @arslansana Your are right. People who have down voted this question should come forward and explain their stand.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your problem at my system:

1) I create a package named `firstProjject`

2) I put the class `Apples.java` in the directory named `firstProjject`

3) I do not provide the package declaration in the class `Apple` which is : `package firstProjject;`

4) I try to run the class in spite of seeing compilation error. As a result I get following error from eclipse:

[image]

So now I think it is clear to you where lies the mistake. Please provide package declaration. Hope it helps.